# Store ACF fields in variables

Tags: wordpress

Im creating a WP-page using Advanced custom fields.
I have a fieldgroup that consists of 2 fields:

Title - a text-field
Columnsection - a repeaterfield which contains 2 WYSIWYG-fields called left_col and right_col.

So the result may look like:

```
Cars (title)
image of a volvo (left_col)        text about a volvo(right_col)
image of a BMW (left_col)          text about a BMW(right_col)
image of a Fiat (left_col)         text about a Fiat(right_col)
```

Ok,so what I am trying to do in my template is to create three variables that will hold all the values:

```
$titles = all Titles
$left_col = all left_cols
$right_col = all right_cols
```

The fieldgroup is called `repeater` so I can do:

```
<?php
 while( have_rows('repeater') ): the_row();                                 
        $title = get_sub_field('main_title');
        $rows = get_sub_field( 'column_section' );
        $left = $rows['left_column'];
        $right = $rows['right_column'];
        echo $title; // Title echoes out
        echo $left; // nothing (expecting array of left_cols 'related to the title')
        echo $right; //nothing (expecting array of right_cols 'related to the title')
        ?>
```

The reason im trying to do this is that I would like to have the right_columns and the left_columns separated  in order to use them in different places in the template.

Help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the docs about nested repeaters: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct syntax for a nested repeater.

```
<?php
while ( have_rows('repeater') ): the_row();                                 
    $title = get_sub_field('main_title');
    echo $title; // Title echoes out

    while ( have_rows( 'column_section') ) : the_row();

        $left = get_sub_field( 'left_column ');
        $right = get_sub_field( 'right_column ');

        echo $left; // nothing (expecting array of left_cols 'related to the title')
        echo $right; //nothing (expecting array of right_cols 'related to the title')

    endwhile;

endwhile;
```

You can view the official docs here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/